# Sort vector pair using STL C++

Tags: c++

I want to sort a vector pair in desending order based on the value of first.If the value of first is same,I want to sort it in ascending order based on the value of second.Is there some way in STL to do this?
Suppose this is my vector pair-

```
(3,u)
(1,d)
(3,t)
```

If I use this-

```
vector < pair <int ,char > >M1(3);
sort(M1.rbegin(),M1.rend());
```

This gives me-

```
(3,u)
(3,t)
(1,d)
```

But this is what I want-

```
(3,t)
(3,u)
(1,d)
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a custom comparison for those pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is provide a comparator (or override `operator<`) for `std::pair`.

Example:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
bool customComparison(const std::pair<T, U> &p1, const std::pair<T, U> &p2)
{
    return std::tie(p2.first, p1.second) < std::tie(p1.first, p2.second);
}

sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), customComparison<int,char>);
```

Comment: Your condition is wrong (when `(p2.first < p1.first)` result should be false in all case). OP wants `return std::tie(p2.first, p1.second) < std::tie(p1.first, p2.second);`

Comment: Overriding `operator <` for **STD** `::pair` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Nitori Also I am getting this error-
`candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
   sort(M1.begin(),M1.end(),customComparison);`

Comment: Ah I see, you're right Jarod. I've updated the logic. Also I fixed the issue about argument counts (the template wasn't auto-deducing like I'd hoped).